# Google Drive API 'md5Checksum' does not work on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am working on a script to look for duplicated files and I am trying to use 'md5Checksum' but reports me a KeyError. Do you know if it really works?

Thank you for your time.

```
FILES = SERVICE.children().list(folderId='root',
                                q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document'"
                               ).execute().get('items', [])
for item in FILES:
    fi = SERVICE.files().get(fileId=item['id']).execute()
    if fi['title'] == "Test":
        print('The name is: %s and md5 is: %s' % (fi['title'], fi['md5Checksum']))
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driveBlueberry_v2\check_md5.py", line 20, in <module>
    print('The name is: %s and md5 is: %s' % (fi['title'], fi['md5Checksum']))
KeyError: 'md5Checksum'
```

Comment: what do you get output if you print `fi` before the if statement

Comment: If I print(fi) it shows al the metadata of the file, but it no appears nothing about 'md5Checksum'

Comment: as an aside, that's a pretty ugly way to get the files. Just do a file.list parent in 'root' and you'll get all the metadata in a single fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Google Drives API V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource-representations):

> md5Checksum - string - The MD5 checksum of the revision's content.  This is only applicable to files with binary content in Drive.

So if your document does not contain binary data, there will not be an md5Checksum field in the metadata.  The [Google Drives API V2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource-representations) explicitly said that it was not populated for Google Documents:

> md5Checksum - string - An MD5 checksum for the content of this file. This field is only populated for files with content stored in Drive; it is not populated for Google Docs or shortcut files.

It is not obvious why they removed the reference to Google Documents in the V3 API.  Either way it is clear that the md5Checksum field will not be populated for every file, so you should use something like:

```
if fi['title'] == "Test":
    print('The name is: %s and md5 is: %s' % (fi['title'], fi.get('md5Checksum'))
```

This avoids throwing the exception and returns `None` as expected if the field is not populated.

Comment: And, of course, Python will be happy to calculate the md5 hash for you via the md5 module, for those other files.  The issue may become that the Google documents files may change in unexpected ways without any visible/content changes, so things may not compare by md5 while containing the exact same content.