# Uploading binary file Google Drive using Python API still does not show md5Checksum metadata

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I need to check to see that a file that I have uploaded to my Google Drive account needs to be updated with the original file I have on my local harddrive.  For this purpose, I would like to use some hash such as a md5sum. So the `md5Checksum` metadata on files stored on the Drive seems to be the best fit (baring that, I'd look for modification time stamps but that is less appealing given the burden of dealing with date/time conversion). So, using code of below, with a known fileId:

```py
fileId = 'whatever'  # gotten from a previous upload using MediaFileUpload():
fi = drive_service.files().get(fileId=fileId).execute()
import pprint
pprint.pprint(fi)
md5Checksum = fi.get('md5Checksum')
print("\n{}\nmd5Checksum\n{}".format('-' * 80, md5Checksum))
```

it returns:

```
{u'id': u'whatever',
 u'kind': u'drive#file',
 u'mimeType': u'application/octet-stream',
 u'name': u'the_name_of_that_file_I_uploaded'}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
md5Checksum
None
```

As indicated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623919/257924, the `md5Checksum` value will be available only to binary files. But since the `mimeType` shown above is `application/octet-stream`, shouldn't it be available?  Isn't `application/octet-stream` equivalent to it being a "binary" file upload?

What I cannot do is simply download the file and run the `md5sum` Linux utility (or equivalent Python code to do the same) to check that it is different, because then that defeats the whole point of checking to see if the file actually needs to be updated (deleted and the re-uploaded, or uploading a new version, etc.).

Update #1: This is not the same as [Google Drive API 'md5Checksum' does not work on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622133/google-drive-api-md5checksum-does-not-work-on-python) as I am not using the list api to obtain the file id. I am just using the id that I found by a previous upload to retrieve metadata on that file, and I am hoping to see some type of hash value indicating its content, and specifically on a file that I *think* (hope) is considered "binary".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Drive API 'md5Checksum' does not work on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622133/google-drive-api-md5checksum-does-not-work-on-python)

Comment: I updated the content with Update #1 explaining why I think this is not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is exposed in the Python API, but in the REST API you would configure the request with a `fields` query parameter that includes `md5Checksum`.  For example `fields=id,kind,mimeType,name,md5Checksum`.